# No agarran los colores en Css con las variables

Tags: html, css

estoy intentando ponerle un color al texto en mi html con este codigo, usando variables que creo que es la mejor practica(parte :root)

```
:root{
    --background-color: #f5f5f5;
    --color-letter: #ff5733
}

body{
    background-color: var(--background-color);
    color: var(--color-letter);
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: stretch;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

li{
    margin-right: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: var(--color-letter)
}

li:first-child{
   margin-right: 800px;
   margin-left: 15px;
}
```

sin embargo no se ve el color en --color-letter, no lo quiero agarrar y lo que aparece es el color por default(azul) en el navegador

Comment: Hola. El CSS que manejas se comporta adecuadamente. ¿Has intentado borrar la cache del navegador? Algunos navegadores recargan todos los componentes cuando combinas la tecla shift con el click en actualizar

Comment: probe y nada,@AbrahamChan

Comment: ¿podrías poner en tu pregunta la sección html, para validar que la forma en la que ligas el archivo css esté correcta? quizá sea de que no se puede acceder al recurso o algún detalle en el src del archivo css. Igual puedes abrir la consola (inspeccionar) y en la sección de red puedes validar lo que se está cargando

Comment: Que navegador estás utilizando? Intenta abrir la app con otro navegador y comentá el resultado por favor.

Comment: Me parece que en la parte :root te faltó un ; (punto y coma)